# Problem with second Flask Apps on Apache2

Tags: python, flask, apache2

I have two domains, pointing to the same (apache2) server. I use two equal Virtual Host files to route the requests to the desired directories. In both directories I have the exactly same WSGI script (except for the path of course). However, for the first directory flask is up and running, but for the second I just see the index overview of desired folder but flask is not running. 
Has anyone an idea what could cause this problem?

Here is the Virtual Host Config:

```
<VirtualHost www.domain1.de:80>
    ServerName www.domain1.de
    ServerAlias domain2.de *.domain2.de
    ServerAdmin admin@domain1.de
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/domain1/domain1.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/html/domain1/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost www.domain2.de/:80>
    ServerName www.domain2.de
    ServerAlias domain2.de *.domain2.de
    ServerAdmin admin@domain2.de
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/domain2/domain2.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/html/domain2/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here are the standard flask snippeds:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug=True
    app.run()
```

And here is the WSGI file. Its the same for both apps, I of course changed the path accordingly:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/domain1')
from init import app as application
```

Comment: Can you post your Apache2 and flask configuration ? Without more info I'd say your flask servers might be running on the same port ?

Comment: Thank you Taek for taking time, I added the code snippeds. I hope its what you need to get a better picture... Thanks for support again!

Answer (score 0):

For everyone facing the same problem, I solved it with the following Virtual Host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost www.domain1.de:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@admin.de
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        WSGIDaemonProcess domain1 user=youruser group=yourgroup threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias /domain1 /var/www/html/domain1/domain1.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/html/domain1>
        WSGIApplicationGroup domain1
        WSGIProcessGroup domain1
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess domain2 user=youruser group=yourgroup threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias /domain2 /var/www/html/domain2/domain2.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/html/domain2>
        WSGIApplicationGroup domain2
        WSGIProcessGroup domain2 
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It turned out, that I had missed the daemonprocess:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess domain1 user=youruser group=yourgroup threads=5
```

A great help was the blog of [Graham Dumpelton](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html):